# How to do test the significant difference of CD4 count less than 350 in relation to different races using SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a pool of CD4 count from 0 to more than 1000, and all the CD4 counts are respect to different races. So how to only test the CD4 count less than 350 to different races? To see whether there is significant difference CD4 counts for different races for CD4 count <350?

Answer (score 2):

This is an inappropriate question to ask.  CD4 count does not work biologically such that something magic happens at 350.  And your power is greatly diminished when you toss information away.  Frame this as a general question, e.g., do CD4 counts tend to be larger for some races than for others?  That would be answered robustly and powerfully using the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: CD4 count less than 350 is a WHO criteria for HIV treatment.  That might be the magic number came from.

Comment: That cutoff has not been validated.  Even if it had, it should not dictate that you do low-power analysis.  Statistical inference should use all the information in the data.  Once you are finished you can convert the result to get a maximum likelihood estimate for the probability of falling below 350.  For parametric models this is a function of the predicted mean and SD.  For ordinal models (e.g., proportional odds model - the generalization of the Kruskal-Wallis and Wilcoxon tests) probabilities of inequalities come directly out of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create in indicator variable that is coded 1 in instances where the CD4 count is less than 350; zero otherwise.  Call that variable CD4ind.  Then you could include an interaction term with your race variable and CD4ind in your model (e.g. $y=CD4ind + race +CD4ind*race$).  If the coefficient associated with the interaction term turns out to be significant, they you have some evidence that CD4 is associated with changes in y differently for different races.

That being said, Frank offers some valuable advice here.